# C++ Creating/Parsing Text File Into a Function

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I'm trying to take input from a text file to call a function. The function takes 3 int paramaters. Each line in the text file will include each int followed by a space. How do I parse each line, call a function using integers from each line, and then exit the loop and close the file? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Here is what the contents of the text file will look like
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
10 11 12

// here is the function
void readValues(int1, int2, int3)
{
    // do something
}

// open text file and parse input. if it does not exist, create file

ifstream file("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);

while (file.eof())
{

    int a, b, c;
    file >> a >> b >> c >> std::endl;
    readValues(a, b, c); // first iteration would be readValues(1, 2, 3)

    if(file.eof())
    {
         break;
    }
}

file.close();
```

Comment: Why did you include the code? What's the question?

Comment: this code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What about this code doesn't work? Include errors, for example, that the compiler outputs.  http://youtube.com/watch?v=786PavIEAOQ

Comment: never use `eof()` to control a loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Also `while (file.eof())` should never run if you just opened a valid file.

Comment: I was having issues building the program. I didn't need the std::endl statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to read a file, you shouldn't also open it for writing (`fstream::out`) *and* truncate it (`fstream::trunc`).

You also shouldn't test for `eof` in your loop condition — there are a few occasions when `eof` is appropriate, but you won't encounter any for your first few years of C++ programming.

And you don't need to explicitly close the file, the destructor handles that.

Do it like this:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");

    int a, b, c;

    while (file >> a >> b >> c)
    {
        readValues(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is almost what I want. How do I create test.txt if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @user3781214 What would you read from it if it doesn't exist?